# Limit Number of Hints a Gamer can Use : Number Guessing Game in C#

Tags: c#, .net, console, console-application, game-engine

I'm designing a Number Guessing Game, that reads a 4 Digit number from the Console.
The computer randomly generates the 4 digit number and the user tries to guess the digits and their correct order. The program returns answer in a format 0A0B or 1A3B or 4A0B e.t.c, where it returns A if the number you guessed in correct and it's position is correct too, and will return B if the number you guessed is correct but it's position is wrong.

I want to implement a hint system, which provides hints when the user types the word 'hint'. How do I limit the number of times a User can type the word 'hint' ?
This is the code I have so far

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    while (true)
    {
            Console.WriteLine("********************************");
            Console.WriteLine("What number do you think it is ?");
            Console.WriteLine("********************************");
            Console.WriteLine();

            bool GameOver = false;
            int[] targetNumber = GenerateRandomNumber(); // Generates the Random Number
            while (!GameOver)
            {
                Console.Write("Answer: ");
                string answer = Console.ReadLine(); // Gets an answer from User

                if (answer.ToLower() == "hint") // Designed to Provide a hint.
                {
                    int Rando = GenerateRandomNumberforHint(); // function I created
                   // Console.WriteLine("The Random Number generated was {0}",Rando);
                    if (Rando == 0)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("{0}XXX", targetNumber[Rando]);
                    }
                    else if (Rando == 1)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("X{0}XX", targetNumber[Rando]);
                    }
                    else if (Rando == 2)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("XX{0}X", targetNumber[Rando]);
                    }
                    else if (Rando == 3)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("XXX{0}", targetNumber[Rando]);
                    }
                    continue;
                }



           /* Code to check if the number is correct */     

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

Do I need to create a Data Structure, and if I do, how do I implement that? I'm extremely new to C Sharp so any help would be appreciated

Comment: What about simple integer variable `int numberOfHintsUsed`? Increment it after each hint and check it before providing a hint

Comment: I think you need to learn some basics of C# if you don't know how to increment integer variable and use `if` operator

Comment: @Kaylo17 I am with Sergey here. This is not "Not a strong pogrammer", it is "cluless beginner whoe never even bothered to read a book". Get yourself a basic C# book (C# in 21 days) and work through that. YOu basically ask how to open - to give a kitchen analogy - a fridge because you are not a good cook. This is utterly super low level basic.

Comment: You're probably both right. I did just start a few days ago, so I'll get there.

Comment: @Kaylo17, nothing wrong with being a beginner. But the others are probably right. Get a basic book and work through it. It will be fun! And then come back to your game, it will be a lot easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is exactly what you want:)

```
int hitcounter = 0;
int lastHint = -1;
while (!GameOver)
{ 
    Console.Write("Answer: ");
    string answer = Console.ReadLine();

    if (answer.ToLower() == "hint")
    {
        if (hitcounter < 10)
        {  
                       //preveintg double hint. something like that. 
                       //you can use later array or list if you need more hint
                       int hint = generaterandomhints();
                       while (hint == lastHint)
                       { 
                           hint = generaterandomhints();
                       }

           hitcounter++;
           //write the hints
        }
        else
        {
            //write you reached the maximum of the hints
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. For some reason, I thought the answer would be extremely complex. This worked like a charm

Comment: If you don't mind, could you answer one question for me. I want to limit the number of hints to 2. But since the number been generated is random, there's a chance it might generate the same number twice in a row. i.E , it will give me the same hint twice and run out of hints. Is there anyway to stop that from happening?

Comment: In my head, I'd say, you either have to stop the random generator from generating the same number twice or find a way to tell the hintcounter  to ignore repeat hints. Is that possible?

Comment: you can store in a variable the last hint and if its same, you generate another one until you get a real new one (eg with a cícle ). Of course you dont increment the hitcounter and donn t show the user anyting until you didnt get the real one

Comment: Sorry but now i have not enugh time. Just some little tips what i can add :D

Comment: If you have some simple question i can solve that :)

Comment: Hey krekkon. I have another question I need your help with. Two questions actually, I'll just copy a link to my code on pastebin, then maybe you can help me from there.

Comment: Hey krekkon. I have another question I need your help with. Two questions actually, I'll just copy a link to my complete program code on pastebin, then maybe you can help me from there.
My questions are: 
1. If I want to limit the number of tries a user has, how would I implement that. I've tried a number of for loops,  basic integer increment with if statements (like the one you showed me), and even while loops , but I can't get it to work.

2. Question. How would you implement a scoring system in such a program.

Any help will be appreciated http://pastebin.com/z2hAKCML